# angularjs - multiple states are selected instead one

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angularjs for my web application and in this I have a `navbar`.
Now in `navbar`, I have different options and I am using `ui-sref-active="active"` to highlight the current `option/state`.

Lets say, I have four options - `Home`, `Admin(with drop-down)`, `features` and `settings(with drop-down)`. Now, if my home state is active and I click on `admin` option, then at the same time it shows both states active(i.e., both `home` and `admin` options are highlighted at the same time instead of one).

Sorry for errors and thanks in advance...

Comment: Please provide the relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class for serving your purpuse.
you can apply below logic for your purpose.

```
<ul>
<li ng-class=setClass("home")>Home</li>
<li ng-class=setClass("Admin")>Admin</li>
<li ng-class=setClass("features")>features</li>
<li ng-class=setClass("settings")>settings</li>
</ul>
```

And in controller create **setClass()** function:

```
    $scope.setclass=function(currentState){

    if(currentState==$state.$current.name){

    return 'active';
    }

    else{

        return '';
}

    };
```

This should work fine.I have used this logic for doing the same.